# java.lang.AssertionError: class hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoPublisher is missing its descriptor when manually building the plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to use JaCoCo code coverage plugin (3.0.4) in Jenkins (2.138.2). It works as expected, but what I don't like about it is that it does not generate the report when the build is either failed or aborted. This code is here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/jacoco/JacocoPublisher.java#L585-L587

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/pull/75) for this, but looks like it didn't get worked on after its original creation.

So I tried to rebuild the plugin myself with next steps:

1. Clone https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin
2. Checkout the latest version 3.0.4
3. Remove the if statement from above in JacocoPublisher class
4. Build the plugin (`mvn package` as they say)

I am able to build it with no problems. The next steps are:

1. Navigate to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced
2. Upload the generated jacoco.hpi file and restart Jenkins

After this is done, the Post Build step to run JaCoCo reports disappears, and I see this in jenkins logs:

```
06-Nov-2018 17:19:24.353 WARNING [Handling GET /jenkins/job/testing-jacoco-code-coverage-reports/configure from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 : http-nio-8080-exec-3 Job/configure.jelly Project/configure-entries.jelly] hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate Caught exception evaluating: i.descriptor in /jenkins/job/testing-jacoco-code-coverage-reports/configure. Reason: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: class hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoPublisher is missing its descriptor
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.getDescriptorOrDie(Jenkins.java:1517)
        at hudson.tasks.Publisher.getDescriptor(Publisher.java:122)
        at hudson.tasks.Recorder.getDescriptor(Recorder.java:51)
        at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoPublisher.getDescriptor(JacocoPublisher.java:775)
        ... 168 more
```

The [solution for this issue](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/My+class+is+missing+descriptor) proposed by Jenkins is not applicable here since the plugin already extends the required classes.
Reverting to previous version (3.0.4 but not of my custom build) makes the build step appear again, but again, is lacking the behavior I need.

Am I missing anything?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the original version, I had to also delete the remaining jacoco plugin files from the /plugins folder. After that, installation went fine.